# SEO Friendly NextJS Menu Button

Tags: javascript, next.js, seo

I have built a component that basically is structured like this:

```
const items = [
  { name: 'New Order', description: 'Place a neworder', href: '/order', icon: NewspaperIcon },
  { name: 'Browse Cocktails', description: 'Browse', href: '/browse', icon: ChartBarIcon },
  { name: 'Pricing', description: "Learn about our premium model", href: '/pricing', icon: WalletIcon },
]
```

In the JSX I have:

```
{items.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.name} className="group relative flex gap-x-1 rounded-lg p-1 hover:bg-gray-50">
                  <div className="mt-0 flex h-10 w-10 flex-none items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gray-50 group-hover:bg-white">
                    <item.icon className="h-6 w-6 text-gray-600 group-hover:text-indigo-600" aria-hidden="true" />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <Link href={item.href} className="font-semibold text-gray-900">
                      {item.name}
                      <span className="absolute inset-0" />
                    </Link>
                    <p className="mt-0 text-sm text-gray-600">{item.description}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
```

What I am noticing is the href's in the Link are not being crawled when using a test crawler.  Why is that?  How can I fix that?